# Null em UploadFile de componente do Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou tendo problemas ao tentar recuperar esse arquivo,`file`, no meu bean.

**.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <p:fileUpload value="#{bean.file}" 
                    skinSimple="true" mode="simple" />
 <p:commandButton value="Enviar" ajax="true"
                    action="#{bean.addFile}" /></h:form>
```

**Bean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean{

    private UploadedFile file;


    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setfile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void addFile() {
        try {
            String fileName = file.getFileName();
            File fileOut = new File(fileName);

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);
            fileOutputStream.write(file.getContents());
            fileOutputStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Ao tentar acessar o atributo `file`, no método `addFile()`, chamado pelo `commandButton`, o atributo `file` não está setado com o arquivo que fiz o upload, está setado como null. Não consigo achar o problema, já pesquisei em diversas fontes e não tive êxito.

Os imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;
```

Comment: Tente alterar o atributo `ajax` do `commandButton` para `false`.

Comment: @Henrique já tentei, setando `ajax="false ",` o método `addFile()` nem chamado é

Comment: Altere o atributo `action` do `commandButton` para `actionListener`.

Comment: @Henrique não entendi. atributo `action` do `commandButton`para `commandButton`?

Answer (score 1):

Vejo dois pontos que precisam de atenção:

1. A utilização do `ajax="true"` no componente [`commandButton`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml) quando utilizado em conjunto com o componente [`FileUpload`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml), onde o mesmo está configurado para utilizar o modo simples (`mode="simple"`). Isso se dá pelo fato de que o componente na versão simples não possui suporte a requisições `ajax`. Se realmente necessita deste suporte, pode usar o modo avançado (`mode="advanced"`).
2. A utilização do `action` no componente [`commandButton`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml) está equivocada, pois o `action` deve ser utilizado quando há intenção de navegação entre páginas, ao invés disto, utilize o `actionListener`, que é utilizado em casos onde precisa executar uma lógica relacionada a view, onde não há necessidade de troca de página.

---

Veja um exemplo de como ficaria:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload value="#{bean.file}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Enviar" ajax="false" actionListener="#{bean.addFile}"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Ótimo, concordo. Eu estava utilizando `actionListener` antes, mas troquei pra fazer um teste e não lembrei de corrigir

Comment: estou usando o `ajax="false"` também.